# Node JS and custom module with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this little piece of code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = MainCtrl;

function MainCtrl() {
  this.defaultUrl = 'http://foo/';
}

MainCtrl.prototype.getPoi = function getPoi() {
  request( 'http://foo/',function(error,response,body) {
    console.log( body );
  });
};
```

and on my route file I require like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var main_lib = require('../lib/main_ctrl.js');

var router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/newroute', function(req,res) {
  //var mainCtrl = new main_lib.MainCtrl();
  main_lib.getPoi();


  res.render('newroute', { title: 'New Route' });
})

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see is very simple, I'm on my first steps with ExpressJS and NodeJS but I don't know why I've got this error:

**TypeError: Object function MainCtrl() { this.defaultUrl = 'http://foo/'; } has no method 'getPoi'**

I've look at the definition of the view module on express lib and is the same as:

```
module.exports = View;

function View(name, options) { .. }
View.prototype.lookup = function lookup(name) { .. }
```

But I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Manwal He has that, that's not the error here. In order to use your prototype you need to instantiate your controller with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error for calling function of `MainCtrl` you need to create object of this class.

Use following code

```
'use strict';

function MainCtrl() {
  this.defaultUrl = 'http://foo/';
}

MainCtrl.prototype.getPoi = function getPoi() {
  request( 'http://foo/',function(error,response,body) {
    console.log( body );
  });
};
//added function for getting instance
module.exports.getInstance = function () {
    return new MainCtrl();
};
```

While adding controller in router use this:

```
var main_lib = require('../lib/main_ctrl.js').getInstance();
```

Now `main_lib` is object of your controller. So you can call like:

```
main_lib.getPoi();
```

---

If you want to use like `View` module then manually you have to create object for this. like

```
'use strict';

module.exports = MainCtrl;

function MainCtrl() {
  this.defaultUrl = 'http://foo/';
}

MainCtrl.prototype.getPoi = function getPoi() {
  request( 'http://foo/',function(error,response,body) {
    console.log( body );
  });
};
```

In route file:

```
var main_lib = require('../lib/main_ctrl.js');

var main_lib_object  = new main_lib();//take a look here
main_lib_object.getPoi(parameter);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, like this work as expected. But why on node_modules/express/lib/view.js is declared in a different way? What's the difference between the View class and mine?

Comment: Updated answer check it.